# How to obtain the keystore's sha1 programmatically

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-keystore

I want to secure my rest api with oauth2 client credential grant specification like what we see in google services for android like Drive and Maps api.

In google service the keystore SHA1 key which our app is signed with is the client id, We store this SHA1 key in the google developer console which then it is used to authorize and authenticate the requests from our app.

So How to obtain the keystore's sha1 programmatically?

Comment: hey @pedram have you find the solution?

Comment: @Prasad I'm afraid not.